# Run task after each test case

Tags: java, junit, testng, code-coverage, jacoco

I am trying to develop a tool to perform some internal data mapping of test cases. To be precise, I want to map which test case hits which all classes and methods. I plan to take JaCoCo dump after each test case, preferably prefixed with test case name.

Without changing the existing test case source (i.e. can't use @AfterClass and other annotations), is it possible in TestNG and JUnit to run a script/program after each test case finishes?

The tool has to be generic. I have TestNG/JUnit test suite files triggered with Gradle build files. I want to let them run while JaCoCo agent is listening and as soon as each test finishes, I want to trigger the JaCoCo ant task to take the dump.

There are over 2000 tests so modifying them is out of question. I was thinking more along in terms of if TestNG and JUnit listeners can be extended to achieve this.

Comment: There isn't really enough information here, if the question is "_can I change the behaviour of code without changing the code_", then (by definition) no. Why don't you tell us 1) how you run your unit tests and 2) what you _can_ change?

Comment: Updated the question. Please see if you have the information you need.

Comment: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners

Comment: Awesome! Is there anything similar for JUnit? Also, kindly post as answer so I can accept.

Comment: Perhaps http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html